# Como fazer um programa ser executado dentro de uma janela em pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Eu fiz uma janela usando pygame, e tenho um código que queria que fosse executado dentro dela, mas não sei como fazer isso, se alguém puder ajudar eu fico muito grato.

Aqui o código da janela:

```
pygame.init()
tela = pygame.display.set_mode([500, 400])
pygame.display.set_caption('Redenção')
relogio = pygame.time.Clock()
cor_branca = (255,255,255)
cor_azul = (108, 194, 236)

sair = False

while sair != True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sair = True
    relogio.tick(27)
    tela.fill(cor_azul)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

e aqui tem o código que quero que seja executado dentro da janela:

```
def intro():

    print("▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄\n")
    print("Durante a 3ª guerra mundial, que explodiu no dia 12 de março do ano 2065 entre as nações mundiais...\n")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("A OTAN das quais fazem parte EUA, Europa ocidental e mais alguns países da parte oriental, como Austrália,\n"
          "Japão e Coreia do Sul, entrou em conflito com o B.R.C.I.S a aliança entre Brasil, Rússia, China,\n"
          "Índia e Africa do Sul.\n")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Como consequência, a fome se espalhou pelo mundo, as intrigas entre as nações aumentaram,\n"
          "surgiram agitações nas grandes cidades e o que todos temiam, a caixa de Pandora foi aberta, as terrivéis\n"
          "bombas atômicas começaram espalhar seu terror pelo mundo...\n")
    time.sleep(5)
    print(
        "O Brasil, por possuir um vasto território e abundantes recursos naturais, se tornou um alvo fácil para as\n"
        "maiores potências mundiais, os países da OTAN temendo uma escassez completa, iniciaram um invasão pelo\n"
        "norte do país, com a intenção de dominar toda a nação e explorar sua grande extensão cultivável...\n")
    time.sleep(6)
    print("O B.R.C.I.S começou um contra-ataque ao saber que o Brasil estava sendo atacado, adentraram o Brasil,\n"
          "inciando pelos estados do nordeste e começam um bombardeio contra a OTAN....\n")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("No dia 25 de novembro de 1965, as nações já se encontravam exaustas em consequência da guerra, veem como\n"
          "última solução, usar as mortais G-BOMBS e o Brasil se torna um cenário de devastação, com milhares de\n"
          "mortos e cidades destruídas.\n")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Nesse inferno na terra, você é um dos poucos sobreviventes em meio ao caos e irá com o restante das suas\n")
```

Comment: E qual é o resultado esperado? Cada string aparecendo após um tempo determinado? Você poderia rever a indentação do seus códigos na pergunta? Parece ter muita coisa errada e ela é fundamental para a compreensão correta do seu código.

Comment: Foi no momento de colar, o código ficou bagunçado, seria melhor colocar uma imagem?

Comment: exatamente como você citou, cada string aparecendo na janela consecutivamente após o tempo determinado.

Comment: Não, basta formatá-lo corretamente no seu editor, colar aqui no SOpt, selecionar todo o código e pressionar Ctrl+K.

Comment: Grato, farei isso para melhorar a compreensão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Pygame te dá uma janela para desenhar, e algumas primitivas de desenho.

Não tem uma forma fácil de colocar texto dentro de uma janela de pygame - e  as técnicas de saída de terminal, em que o texto rola pra cima automaticamente não se misturam nem um pouco com a API que o pygame disponibiliza.

A forma de colocar texto numa janela do pygame tem 3 passos:

1. cria um objeto Fonte, onde você escolhe a fonte em si (typeface e o tamanho)
2. cria uma `Surface` com o texto escrito. Nesse passo você fornece os caractéres que quer escrever na tela e a cor desejada - ele te devolve um retângulo com o texto desenhado e fundo transparente.
3. Você "carimba" (método `.blit`) esse texto desenhado numa posição da tela.

Se o texto for mudar de posição (por que apareceu mais texto embaixo e o texto existente precisa ser empurrado pra cima), você tem que apagar a tela, e repetir os passos 2-3 para o texto que já estava lá.

Tem um problema extra que não aparece aí: o pgame não faz quebra de linha
automática para texto - ele renderiza uma linha. Se a largura máxima do texto na sua janela de jogo for 40 ou 80 caractéres, você que tem que quebrar o texto em pedaços do tamanho apropriado e gerar retângulos com
cada linha, e colar no lugar certo.

Aqui vai o exemplo em código para colocar um "Alô mundo" na tela com pygame:

```
import pygame
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.font.init()
font1 = pygame.font.Font(None, 150)
text = font1.render("Alô Mundo", True, (255, 255, 255))
screen.blit(text, (0, 200))
pygame.display.flip()

def principal():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               return
        pygame.time.delay(30)

principal()
```

(O `None` na chamada a `pygame.font.Font` faz o pygame usar uma fonte padrão, sem serifa - pode ser um caminho para qualquer arquivo de fotnes do tipo "ttf" (e talvez outros))

Tudo isso é factível com programação, claro - mas é bastante coisa pra fazer, e está entre você e o seu conceito de jogo.

O melhor é usar uma camada intermediária que permita texto no pygame - tem o PGU (Phil's Pygame Utilities)  - ele não tem pacotes - mas é fácil instalar baixando direto do github - 
https://github.com/parogers/pgu

Ele permtie a criação de interfaces parecidas com as dos programas de janela dentro da janela do Pygame -  o conceito ainda é diferente do terminal,e não vai funcionar só com "print" e "sleep" - mas  pelo menos ele pode gerenciar a apresentação do texto pra você.

https://github.com/parogers/pgu

Tem um projeto meu também que é o "mapengine"  - ele está bem pouco documentado, mas tem suporte ao que chamo de "cut scenes" - justamente cenas em que dá pra escrever algum texto, e esperar uma ação do usuário, e mudar pra próxima tela - daria pra adaptar fácil esse "contar de história" aí: https://github.com/jsbueno/mapengine/tree/master/mapengine

O mapengine tem suporte para um mapa maior que a tela, e items de "bloco"  como jogos de plataforma  - pode servir bem para desenvolver algum jogo que você tenha em mente sem precisar fazer tudo do zero em cima do pygame. (e se for usar, pode ir me escrevendo pra eu arrumar eventuais problemas/adicionar funcionalidades).  Tem uma pasta de "exemplos" lá.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: você aceitou a resposta, e eu nem tinha acabado ainda - minha mão escorregou aqui e postou sem querer. Tem a sugestão de usar o "PGU"

Comment: adicionei um código de exemplo para uma linha de texto

Comment: Pedi uma resposta e ganhei uma aula, muitooo obrigado, me ajudou demais!